# how to make g++ count errors on compilation

Tags: linux, g++

I am use to using VC++ and like the feature when you compile the program it tells you how many warnings and errors there are so at a quick glance you can tell if you made a positive change.

I am now working in Linux so have to use `g++` and am getting tired of having a massive stream of errors that I have to scroll through and guess at how many there are.

is there a way I can make `g++` count the errors and warnings like VC++ does ?

Comment: go at them one at a time, whatever the count. missing a ';' may add 20 errors. count is not that important IMO

Comment: @Sujoy while I don't disagree with what you said i find it very useful to see if I am going round in circles or making progress. its also useful to say I have eliminated 46 of the 112 errors when the boss wants today's productivity report :(

Comment: not to be rude, but thats what test suites are for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ g++ 2>&1 | tee /proc/self/fd/3 | grep Error | wc -l } 3>&1
```

Comment: what do i do with that code, i know almost nothing about linux or g++ atm.

Comment: It's shell syntax. It counts up all the lines in the output containing Error.

Comment: so do i type that in the terminal after i have compiled the program ? sorry im not useto doing anything outside the ide, linux is rather confusing to me

Comment: You type that in the terminal (with whatever you pass to g++ immediately following g++) as the command to compile. Pro tip: stuff like this is best stored in a file such as compile.sh (or a Makefile when you get to there) so you don't type it every time.